# Calling my REST API from my action method instead of calling it directly from my view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following page to initiate an API call, but I need to know if it is possible to make this call from an action method instead of directly from my view. I need to call the API from the actin method for these reasons:-

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Save Asset Form</title>
    <link href="/style/api-style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm(
   null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { @action = "http://win-spdev:8400/servlets/AssetServlet" }
))
 {
        <table width="650" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border:1px #ccc solid" align="center">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">Save Asset Form</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" width="142">Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="txt" NAME="assetName" style="width:160px;" /></td>
            <td width="142" align="right">Asset Type</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="txt" NAME="assetType" value="" style="width:160px;" /></td>
        </tr>

        //code goes here..............................................................
                <td align="right" width="142">Associate To Department</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="txt" NAME="associateToDepartment" style="width:160px;" /></td>
                <td width="142" align="right">Associate To User</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="txt" NAME="associateToUser" value="" style="width:160px;" /></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
            <table class="innertable" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td class="thd" colspan="4">Authentication details</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" width="142">username</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="txt" NAME="username" style="width:160px;" /></td>
                <td width="142" align="right">password</td>
                <td><input type="password" class="txt" NAME="password" value="" style="width:160px;" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="right" width="142">domain</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="txt" NAME="DOMAIN_NAME" style="width:160px;" /></td>
                <td align="right" width="142">Authentication Mode</td>
                <td><INPUT TYPE=radio NAME="logonDomainName" value="Local Authentication" >Local Authentication&nbsp;
                <INPUT TYPE=radio NAME="logonDomainName" value="AD_AUTH" >AD Authentication</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4" height="10"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="4" class="footer"><input type="submit" name="operation" value="SaveAsset" class="btnsubmitact"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
}
```

1. I need to log the call to my own database, so after finishing the API call, I need to log the call with the API status (either success or failure).
2. I need to manipulate the return XML and display a more user friendly error message , or even if the API call sussed I want to redirect to an action method with my asp.net mvc.

Any advice on how I can transform the API call from my view to my action method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to know if it is possible to make this call from an action method instead of directly from my view

Yep, you just need to fire up a [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and send it from inside your action or use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) if it's just a simple request.